# C: converting const strings into regular strings

Tags: c, string, constants

I'm given a function that has a const char* as a parameter in C.  How do I convert it to a regular char* in order to do string operations on it? When I have the following, I get the following: *warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]*

```
char* pathname_lookup(const char* pathname) {
    assert (pathname[0] == '/');
    char* path = ""; 
    strcpy(path, pathname);
    path = path + 1;
    return path;
}
```

How do I convert the const string into a string I can do string operations on?

Answer (score 4):

```
char* path = ""; 
strcpy(path, pathname)
```

This doesn't make sense. Here, `path` points to a constant. So when you try to copy a string into it, you're trying to change a constant which, of course, you can't do because by definition, constants cannot have their value changed.

Perhaps you want:

```
char *path = strdup(pathname);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is broken, it tries to copy the incoming string into the space occupied by the string literal `""`, which is illegal (literal strings are read-only).

You must allocate heap memory and copy the string in there.

This can be done with [`strdup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup), which isn't standard but pretty common.

You can re-implement it like so:

```
char * my_strdup(const char *s)
{
  char *out = NULL;
  if(s != NULL)
  {
    if((out = malloc(strlen(s) + 1) != NULL)
      strcpy(out, s);
  }
  return out;
}
```

The above could be micro-optimized but that should suffice for most uses.

Comment: One thing C teaches over the years is humility... Check my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944390/what-is-the-rationale-for-not-including-strdup-in-the-c-standard

Comment: @chqrlie Absolutely. And ouch.