# Allocation memory to char**

Tags: c, dynamic, realloc, calloc

The program aims to get the first word and an array of remaining words. For example, if `line = "a bb cc dd ee"`, then `key` should be `a`, `keySet` should be a pointer to an array of `{bb,cc,dd,ee}`.

I try to dynamically allocate memory to `char** keySet`, but keySet output always `ee ee ee ee`. It seems that keySet is not the pointer to the first element of array but point to the last element. What's the problem in my function?

```
void allocateKeySet(char* line){
    int count = 0;
    char* token = strtok(line, " ");
    char key[17];
    char tempKey[17];
    char** keySet;

    sscanf(strtok(NULL, " "), " %s", key);
    keySet = calloc(1, sizeof(char*));
    while((token = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL){
        sscanf(token, " %s", tempKey);
        keySet[count++] = tempKey;
        keySet = realloc(keySet, (count+2) * sizeof(char*));
    }

    printf("key: %s\n", key);
    printf("keySet: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++){
        printf("%s ", keySet[i]);
    }
}
```

e.g.
line:

```
"a bb cc dd ee"
```

expected output:

```
key: a
keySet: bb cc dd ee
```

My output:

```
key: a
keySet: ee ee ee ee
```

Comment: `keySet[count++] = tempKey;`: you probably want `str(n)cpy`, or `strdup`. Currently, `tempKey` gets reassigned everytime, and all `keySet` elements point to *the same* `tempKey`. Hence, after the last `tempKey` assignment, they all point to `"ee"`. (Note that if you use `strcpy`, you'll need to assign memory for `keySet[count++]` first; `strdup` does the allocation and assignment in one go, but you'll have to test for `NULL` anyway afterwards.)

Comment: you mean: `strdup(keySet[count++],  tempKey )`?

Comment: Almost: `keySet[count++] = strdup(tempKey)`. Do test for `keySet[count-1] != NULL` afterwards (unlikely, but the proper thing to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keySet[count++] = tempKey;`: you probably want `str(n)cpy`, or `strdup`. Currently, `tempKey` gets reassigned everytime, and all `keySet` elements point to *the same* `tempKey`. Hence, after the last `tempKey` assignment, they all point to `"ee"`. (Note that if you use `strcpy`, you'll need to assign memory for `keySet[count++]` first; `strdup` does the allocation and assignment in one go, but you'll have to test for `NULL` anyway afterwards.)

Thus:

```
while((token = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL){
        sscanf(token, " %s", tempKey);
        keySet[count] = strdup(tempKey);
        if (keySet[count] == NULL) {
             perror("memory allocation failure");
        }
        count++;
        keySet = realloc(keySet, (count+2) * sizeof(char*));
    }
```

If you can't use `strdup`, you can use the following lines instead of the `strdup` line:

```
keySet[count] = malloc(strlen(tempKey)+1);
// test for keySet[count] 1= NULL
strcpy(keySet[count], tempKey)
count++;
```

as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14021039/707650).

Don't forget to free the individual `keySet` elements afterwards.

Comment: If I want to use `strcpy`, how can I assign memory for `keySet[count++]`? Something like `keySet[count++] = char[strlen(tempKey)]`? Cuz `strdup` seems not in standard C library and I can't use it in my homework...

Comment: What OS are you using. `strdup` is a POSIX.1-2001 standard, and is around in most C libraries.

Comment: And some discussion on why it's not the C standard otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944390/what-is-the-rationale-for-not-including-strdup-in-the-c-standard

Comment: We can only use the libraries provided. And thank you! `strcpy` works