# Getting an unexpected breakpoint when trying to print a doubly linked list

Tags: c

I am getting an unexpected break point when I am trying to print out my doubly linked list. The unexpected break point is popping out in the `printSongInfo` function in the dsA1LL.cpp on the line

```
while (ptr != NULL) {
    printf("%-35s %-35s %-35d\n", ptr->title, ptr->artist, ptr->rating);
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

//New just added
I completed some changes to the piece of code and now it not printing out the list. It is only printing out the first Node.

This will only print one line then the break point appears. I am wondering if it is the `printSongInfo` function or if it is the doubly linked list function `getSongInfo` causing the issue.
Source code dsA1.cpp file

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include"dsA1.h"
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#pragma warning(disable : 6387)


int main() {


    char title[kStringLength];
    char artist[kStringLength];
    int rating = 0; 
    SongNode* head = NULL; 
    SongNode* tail = NULL; 



    printf("Enter Title, Artist and Rating\n");
    printf("Enter'.' to get out of the loop and print list\n");
    
    while (kInfiniteLoop) {

        printf("Title: "); 
        fgets(title, kStringLength, stdin); 
        eliminateEndOfLine(title); 

        if (strcmp(title, ".") == 0) {
            break;
        }

        printf("Artist: "); 
        fgets(artist, kStringLength, stdin);
        eliminateEndOfLine(artist);
            
        printf("Rating: "); 
        while (rating = getNum()) { // error check the rating this will check to make sure the rating is in the range 1-5.

            if (rating<1||rating>5){
                printf("The number you have entered is invaild\n");
                rating = 0; 
                printf("Rating: "); 
                continue; 
            }
            break; 
        }
        head = getSongInfo(head, title, artist, rating); 
    }
    
    printSongInfo(head); 
    return 0;
}
```

dsA1.h header file

```
#pragma once

//structs 
typedef struct SongNode {
    char* title;
    char* artist;
    int rating; 
    SongNode* next;
    SongNode* prev; 
}SongNode;

//Constants 
#define kInfiniteLoop 1 
#define kStringLength 30

//Prototypes
SongNode* getSongInfo(SongNode* head, char title[kStringLength], char artist[kStringLength], int rating);
void printSongInfo(SongNode* head); 
int getNum(void); 
void eliminateEndOfLine(char* buffer);
```

dsA1LL.cpp other source code file

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include "dsA1.h"
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#pragma warning(disable : 6387)

SongNode* getSongInfo(SongNode *head, char title[kStringLength], char artist[kStringLength],int rating) {
    
    SongNode* newNode; 
    newNode = (SongNode*)malloc(sizeof(SongNode));
    if (newNode == NULL) {
        printf("No Memory left\n"); 
        return head;
    }

    newNode->title = (char*)malloc(strlen(title) + 1); 
    if (newNode->title == NULL) {
        printf("No memory left for title\n"); 
        return head; 
    }

    newNode->artist = (char*)malloc(strlen(artist) + 1); 
    if (newNode->rating == NULL) {
        printf("No memory left for artist\n"); 
        return head; 
    }

    
    strcpy(newNode->title, title); 
    strcpy(newNode->artist, artist);
    newNode->rating = rating; 

    if (head == NULL) {
        head = newNode;
        return head; 
    }

    head->prev = newNode;
    newNode->next = head; 
    
    return head; 
}

void printSongInfo(SongNode* head) {
    SongNode* ptr;
    ptr = head;

    printf("\n");
    printf("%-35s %-35s\n", "Title", "Artist");

    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("%-35s %-35s %-35d\n", ptr->title, ptr->artist, ptr->rating);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}


/*===============================================================================================================*/
/*FUNCTION   :getNum(void)                                                                                       */
/*PARAMETERS :void                                                                                               */
/*RETURNS    :number                                                                                             */
/*DESCRIPTION:This function is the user input function to get a number rating                                    */
/*===============================================================================================================*/
int getNum(void)
{/* the array is 121 bytes in size; we'll see in a later lecture how we can improve this code */
    char record[121] = { 0 }; /* record stores the string */
    int number = 0;
    /* NOTE to student: indent and brace this function consistent with your others */
/* use fgets() to get a string from the keyboard */
    fgets(record, 121, stdin);
    /* extract the number from the string; sscanf() returns a number
 * corresponding with the number of items it found in the string */
    if (sscanf(record, "%d", &number) != 1)
    {
        /* if the user did not enter a number recognizable by
         * the system, set number to -1 */
        number = -1;
    }
    return number;
}



/*=======================================================================================================*/
/*FUCNTION      :void eliminateEndOfLine                                                                 */
/*PARAMETER     :(char* buffer)                                                                          */
/*RETURNS       :void                                                                                    */
/*DESCRIPTION   :This function takes a pointer to a string and looks through the string to find the      */
/*               newline.It takes the new line out of the string.                                        */
/*=======================================================================================================*/
void eliminateEndOfLine(char* buffer)
{
    char* target = strchr(buffer, '\n');
    if (target != NULL)
    {
        *target = '\0';
    }
}
```

Comment: The narrative mentions .cpp code but the question is tagged 'c'.

Comment: to be clear, what do you mean with breakpoint? are you debugging? or do you mean that the execution is completely stopped?

Comment: I am debugging it and there is unexpected break point appearing when I try to print out my doubly linked list

Comment: In `getSongInfo` you do `malloc`, this allocates but does _not_ copy the string. Add a `strcpy` after or use `strdup` instead

Answer (score 0):

The first node you create doesn't have it's `next` set to `NULL`

An easy fix would be move `newNode->next = head` above the `if (head == NULL)` check. Though IMHO it's clearer to add `newNode->next = NULL` inside that check.

Also looks like you add to the list by prepending. You set newNode->next to head and head->prev to newNode - but you never set head to newNode.

Finally: checkout `strdup` instead of handrolled `malloc`/`strcpy`

Comment: This got rid of the unexpected break point but it is only printing the first node of the list. It isn't printing out the entire list.

Comment: Which means your `ptr->next` is null. Manually walk through the process of adding a second entry to the list and see how you fail to update `head->next`.

Comment: `strdup` is not [standard ISO C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32946031/2472827), though arguably useful.